# Why an IllegalStateException is thrown inside Google Play In-App Review listeners when calling findNavController or requireActivity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, google-play-core

We are using the **Google Play In-App Reviews API**.
Since our last update to the Play Store (last week), we started receiving the following exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException`, inside of the following listeners: `request.addOnCompleteListener` and `request.addOnFailureListener`

In `addOnCompleteListener` it fails when we call `findNavController()` and in `addOnFailureListener` when we call `requireActivity()`.
All this happens inside a **Fragment** and the listeners are called from a function (requestForReviewIfReady) inside  `onResume()`, so `findNavController()` and `requireActivity()` should not throw any exceptions as far as I’m aware.

So far, we have had 3 crash reports and it seems to be happening only in a couple of devices (Redmi 9A (twice) and LGE LG G6) and APIs (9 & 10 (twice)).

The (simplified) code is the following:

```
private fun requestForReviewIfReady() {
        val navController = findNavController() //(1) First call to findNavController(). Here it doesn't fail.
        val manager = context?.let { ReviewManagerFactory.create(it) }
        var reviewInfo: ReviewInfo? = null

        if (someConditions) {

            val request = manager?.requestReviewFlow()

            request?.addOnCompleteListener { requestTask ->
                if (requestTask.isSuccessful) {

                    reviewInfo = requestTask.result

                    with(navController) {
                        if (currentBackStackEntry?.destination == graph[R.id.mainFragment]) {
                          //Some unimportant code
                          val navController_2 = findNavController() //(2) Second call to findNavController. It throws an IllegalStateException.

                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    // There was some problem, continue regardless of the result.
                }
            }

            request?.addOnFailureListener {
                //Some unimportant code
                isTestLabDevice(requireActivity()) //(3) Throws IllegalStateException
            }

        }
    }
```

As you can see, at the beginning of `requestForReviewIfReady()` we call `findNavController` (1) and it never fails.
While in (2) it throws the exception. We call `findNavController` again because in the full code we call it just at the beginning of another function (navigateOnlyIfCurrentDestinationIsMainFragment()).

The stack traces are the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getParentFragmentManager(Fragment.java:1059)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment$Companion.findNavController(NavHostFragment.java:375)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentKt.findNavController(Fragment.kt:29)
    at com.example.myApp.mainscreen.MainFragment.navigateOnlyIfCurrentDestinationIsMainFragment(MainFragment.kt:864)
    at com.example.myApp.mainscreen.MainFragment.requestForReviewIfReady$lambda-68(MainFragment.kt:1190)
    at com.example.myApp.mainscreen.MainFragment$$InternalSyntheticLambda$0$bccfb11977a9fae7720b93d357945e2b1fc482677438610617a9f85833e8f048$1.onComplete(MainFragment.java:0)
    at com.google.android.play.core.tasks.zza.run(com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:1)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:914)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:225)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7563)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:994)
```

Following the first stack trace we see that the exception is thrown when
`fragmentManager == null`.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:947)
    at com.example.myApp.mainscreen.MainFragment.changeAdsBackgroundColor(MainFragment.kt:778)
    at com.example.myApp.mainscreen.MainFragment.loadBannerAdWhenAppropriate(MainFragment.kt:760)
    at com.example.myApp.mainscreen.MainFragment.requestForReviewIfReady$lambda-69(MainFragment.kt:1202)
    at com.example.myApp.mainscreen.MainFragment$$InternalSyntheticLambda$0$bccfb11977a9fae7720b93d357945e2b1fc482677438610617a9f85833e8f048$2.onFailure(MainFragment.java:0)
    at com.google.android.play.core.tasks.zzc.run(zzc.java:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.signalgeneration.zzo.run$bridge(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:0)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:914)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:225)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7563)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:994)
```

Following the second stack trace we see that the exception is thrown when `activity == null`

Comment: Maybe when those callbacks fire, the fragment you started the request from no longer has access to its parent activity? e.g. it's been detached

Comment: @cactustictacs I agree. I couldn’t replicate the exceptions as they seem to be edge cases, but you made me reconsider how I implemented the whole review process to be certain that the app is in the correct state before calling certain functions. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah you can't ever be sure what a particular device or manufacturer is up to as far as software tweaks go, and it can be hard to replicate that stuff if you don't have one of those devices to test on - definitely better to be safe! Also if you're using something like Crashlytics, maybe you could do some logging in that situation, and try to work out what's going on - it could be a sign of another issue